# I have two word integer

Tags: cpu-word, 32-bit

I'm working in assembly on a homework problem, and each word is 16bit. So I have a two word 32 bit integer. The high order bits are in R1 (register 1) and the lower order bits are in R0 (register 0). So the number is just "R1R0". I'm supposed to treat it as a continuous number so imagine the number is just both combined. So I want to work with R1R0 as a positive number, so if it is negative I want to take the NOT of R1R0 and add 1 because it is a 2's complement number and doing so would turn it into a positive number. My problem is that if you took the NOT of R1R0 and R0 was a positive number previous and then became a negative number from the NOT what should I do? Should I carry over from the R1 and subtract 1 from R1?

Comment: Ok I'll take that. Also another question I guess. If you carried from R1 into R0. Do you subtract 1 from R1 than add 10000 to R0? or do you just not add at all?